# update Main UI Thread or AsyncTask never allowed than where can i update UI thread?

Tags: android-asynctask, android

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at biz.xicom.printvintage.HomeScreen$2.run(HomeScreen.java:199)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4644)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at biz.xicom.printvintage.HomeScreen.setview(HomeScreen.java:193)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at biz.xicom.printvintage.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:58)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    04-25 13:15:52.362: E/AndroidRuntime(20900):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

**code**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < image_list.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = HomeScreen.this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout childlayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflator.inflate(
                R.layout.image_text_web_services_inflate, mPager, false);
        im = (ImageView) childlayout.findViewById(R.id.image_web_service);
        t = (TextView) childlayout.findViewById(R.id.text_web_service);

        t.setText(HomeScreen.detail_list.get(i));
        final int j=i;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){   
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                                    HomeScreen.image_list.get(j))
                                    .getContent());
                    im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        mPager.addView(childlayout);
    }
```

i read below link:

[Load More - Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253189/load-more-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its)

[android - Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204079/android-caused-by-android-view-viewrootimplcalledfromwrongthreadexception)

**Every one said**

You are trying to update your Main UI Thread or AsyncTask never allowed that.

**then where i can update or show my image.**

Also try **AsyncTask**.
**than how to implement on loop**

Comment: Make and asynctask that in background fetches the bitmap and onPostExecute sets it to your ImageView. Also incorporate caching is another tip. There are loads of examples out there.

Comment: @DavidOlsson im on loop so how can i send loop value to onPostExecute.

Comment: @IceMAN It's not possible duplicate, here issue is somewhat different.

Comment: @HCD, take a read over at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: @IceMAN i now question is repeated i m not satisfying those answer and will u read my question properly.

Comment: @HCD: No need to be rude fella! If my flag is wrong, my apologies. The other users will ignore it if everyone agrees it is wrongly marked duplicate.

Comment: Create a solution for one iteration in the loop and use it for all. Handle the Network stuff in a background thread (Just like all the google answers says and the exception). And then update the ImagView in onPostExecute.

Comment: @IceMAN the thing is nobody can read whole question they just go only for heading thats my bad luck !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to load Images inside Loop, I would suggest you to implement logic of **Lazy loading of Images**.

Here are some libraries you can give a try:

1. [Lazy List](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
2. [Universal Image Loader for Android](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code It will help,

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: where i can put this code in my activity

Comment: before running your thread

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a web service in UI thread. Android does not allow you to perform network operation in UI thread from API>=3.0.

Solutions:

1. Load images in a different thread.

   ```
   new Thread()
   {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
           // load image here
           super.run();
        }
   }.start();
   ```
2. Using [LazyList](https://github.com/king-dev/LazyList) would be a great solution for   this problem.
3. You may use AsyncTask too.

   ```
   class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Runs on UI thread- Any code you wants 
    // to execute before web service call. Put it here.
    // Eg show progress dialog
   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     // Runs in background thread
       String result = //your web service request;         

        return result;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {

     // runs in UI thread - You may do what you want with response 
     // Eg Cancel progress dialog - Use result         
   }
   }
   ```